# Unable to install cartopy on MacOSX

Tags: pip, homebrew, cartopy, geos, proj

### Description

I am unable to install Cartopy on my Mac using pip.
Proj is already installed and works.
GEOS is also installed, but I am not sure if it workes or not.
If anyone has any suggestions to solve this problem, I'd greatly appreciate.

### Code to reproduce and Traceback

```
$ pip install cartopy --no-binary cartopy
Collecting cartopy
  Using cached Cartopy-0.18.0.tar.gz (14.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (1.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely>=1.5.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyshp>=1.1.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (41.2.0)
Skipping wheel build for cartopy, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: cartopy
    Running setup.py install for cartopy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6p/plpj2g0x0vs32g91rsdsx2n80000gn/T/pip-install-eatjklvl/cartopy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6p/plpj2g0x0vs32g91rsdsx2n80000gn/T/pip-install-eatjklvl/cartopy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/6p/plpj2g0x0vs32g91rsdsx2n80000gn/T/pip-record-37x0ie3d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cartopy
         cwd: /private/var/folders/6p/plpj2g0x0vs32g91rsdsx2n80000gn/T/pip-install-eatjklvl/cartopy/
    Complete output (312 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/cartopy
    copying lib/cartopy/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/cartopy

[...]

    copying lib/cartopy/io/srtm.npz -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/cartopy/io
    UPDATING build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/cartopy/_version.py
    set build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/cartopy/_version.py to '0.18.0'
    running build_ext
    building 'cartopy.trace' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/lib
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/lib/cartopy
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include -I./lib/cartopy -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.8.1_1/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c lib/cartopy/trace.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/lib/cartopy/trace.o
    lib/cartopy/trace.cpp:4439:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GEOD_ARCMODE'
      geod_genposition((&__pyx_v_self->geod_line), GEOD_ARCMODE, (__pyx_v_self->a13 * __pyx_v_t), (&__pyx_v_lonlat.y), (&__pyx_v_lonlat.x), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                                                   ^
    lib/cartopy/trace.cpp:8677:3: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      0, /*tp_print*/
      ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    lib/cartopy/trace.cpp:8780:3: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      0, /*tp_print*/
      ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    lib/cartopy/trace.cpp:8865:3: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      0, /*tp_print*/
      ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    lib/cartopy/trace.cpp:8950:3: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      0, /*tp_print*/
      ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    lib/cartopy/trace.cpp:12563:5: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        0,
        ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    5 warnings and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6p/plpj2g0x0vs32g91rsdsx2n80000gn/T/pip-install-eatjklvl/cartopy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6p/plpj2g0x0vs32g91rsdsx2n80000gn/T/pip-install-eatjklvl/cartopy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/6p/plpj2g0x0vs32g91rsdsx2n80000gn/T/pip-record-37x0ie3d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cartopy Check the logs for full command output.
```

## Environment

Mac OS X 10.15.4
pip 20.1
Not using conda.

#### Proj and GEOS

```
$ brew info proj  
proj: stable 7.0.1 (bottled), HEAD
Cartographic Projections Library
https://proj.org/
Conflicts with:
  blast (because both install a `libproj.a` library)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/proj.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘
Required: libtiff ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 12,107 (30 days), 38,315 (90 days), 131,481 (365 days)
install-on-request: 1,635 (30 days), 5,538 (90 days), 17,198 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

$ brew info geos
geos: stable 3.8.1 (bottled)
Geometry Engine
https://trac.osgeo.org/geos
/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.8.1_1 (430 files, 9.7MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-05-09 at 10:03:09
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/geos.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: swig ✘
Required: python@3.8 ✔
==> Analytics
install: 12,717 (30 days), 36,681 (90 days), 121,342 (365 days)
install-on-request: 2,958 (30 days), 8,228 (90 days), 25,122 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

#### pip list

```
$ pip list
Package                    Version
-------------------------- --------------
appdirs                    1.4.3
appnope                    0.1.0
attrs                      19.3.0
backcall                   0.1.0
bidict                     0.19.0
biosppy                    0.6.1
bleach                     3.1.4
certifi                    2020.4.5.1
chromedriver-autoinstaller 0.2.0
chromedriver-binary        83.0.4103.14.0
chromedriver-py            83.0.4103.14
cycler                     0.10.0
Cython                     0.29.17
decorator                  4.4.2
defusedxml                 0.6.0
distlib                    0.3.0
entrypoints                0.3
filelock                   3.0.12
future                     0.18.2
geckodriver-autoinstaller  0.1.0
h5py                       2.10.0
ipykernel                  5.2.0
ipython                    7.13.0
ipython-genutils           0.2.0
ipywidgets                 7.5.1
jedi                       0.16.0
Jinja2                     2.11.1
joblib                     0.14.1
jsonschema                 3.2.0
jupyter                    1.0.0
jupyter-client             6.1.2
jupyter-console            6.1.0
jupyter-core               4.6.3
kiwisolver                 1.2.0
MarkupSafe                 1.1.1
matplotlib                 3.2.1
mistune                    0.8.4
nbconvert                  5.6.1
nbformat                   5.0.5
nolds                      0.5.2
notebook                   6.0.3
numpy                      1.18.4
opensignalsreader          0.2.2
pandas                     1.0.3
pandocfilters              1.4.2
parso                      0.6.2
patsy                      0.5.1
pexpect                    4.8.0
pi                         0.1.2
pickleshare                0.7.5
pip                        20.1
prometheus-client          0.7.1
prompt-toolkit             3.0.5
ptyprocess                 0.6.0
Pygments                   2.6.1
pyhrv                      0.4.0
pyparsing                  2.4.7
pyrsistent                 0.16.0
pyshp                      2.1.0
python-dateutil            2.8.1
pytz                       2019.3
pyzmq                      19.0.0
qtconsole                  4.7.2
QtPy                       1.9.0
scikit-learn               0.22.2.post1
scipy                      1.4.1
seaborn                    0.10.0
selenium                   3.141.0
Send2Trash                 1.5.0
setuptools                 41.2.0
Shapely                    1.7.0
shortuuid                  1.0.1
six                        1.14.0
spectrum                   0.7.6
statsmodels                0.11.1
terminado                  0.8.3
testpath                   0.4.4
tornado                    6.0.4
traitlets                  4.3.3
urllib3                    1.25.9
versioneer                 0.18
virtualenv                 20.0.20
wcwidth                    0.1.9
webencodings               0.5.1
wheel                      0.34.2
widgetsnbextension         3.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I uninstalled Shapely, GEOS, Proj, and re-installed them.
Then again `pip install cartopy --no-binary cartopy` then it worked.

Comment: Can you explain in more depth what you did?